# HashID and NameHash

Tags: python

What to do in a segment project that as DocHashID and NameHash. How should we manage does variables?

I tried count the number of times but there are some IDHash docs that are in database. But it is hard to understand how can be useful or what to do with it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: DocIDHash  Count  \
0       0xE3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B...   3021   
1       0xA486FBACF4B4E5537B026743E3FDFE571D716839E758...     31   
2       0x2B17E9D2CCEF2EA0FE752EE345BEDFB06741FFC8ECEC...     24   
3       0x469CF1F9CF8C790FFA5AD3F484F2938CBEFF6435BCFD...     15   
, hello thank you for the interest in helping me, ehat can I do in a segmentation case, eith this hash?